# How to count the number values in a date range?

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula

Using Google Sheets, I am trying to figure out how to count the number of values that fall in a specific date range (within a week of today). In column `A` I have dates, and column `B` I have fruits. I want to see how many bananas are within a week of Today (ex. Today minus 7 days).
*See attached picture with my layout.*

Currently I am using the formula:

```
=countifs(B2:B21, "Banana", A2:A21, (B23-7))
```

where `B23` is today's date. The formula says there's only 1 Banana value, when I know there should be more.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to slightly adjust your formula to:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B21, "Banana", A2:A21, ">"&B23&-7)
```

If you want to always get last week's count, you could use the following

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B21, "Banana", A2:A21, ">"&(TODAY()-7))
```

Functions used:

- [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting the answer of "4" when I believe as of Today (5/1/20) the formula should be counting "6" bananas.

Comment: *"I tried this, but ..."* Which one? The 1st or the 2nd formula? If still in trouble, could you please share a test sheet?

Comment: I tried both - each one provided the output of "4"      https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r946gGDue4wZU1Kgto-i168HMWkZTHJgM4gxV32FAa4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet is private. Please change permissions to public. If it carries sensitive date, prepare a dummy one as [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311)

Comment: My apologies - try this link. I have made it public.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NzjHe6n4YNm8KH1sHSYwRhp-J8e-o3uIbM-vaOaWaAw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212928/discussion-between-marikamitsos-and-elise).

Comment: I had a look at your sheet. I am afraid that is just how many "bananas" you have during that period. :)  *IF you want to include today* -which makes it 8 days- you just add = to the formula `>=` instead of `>`. Then you get `6` because the 24th is included. So the formula counts correctly. It is up to you to decide what to include. If this clarifies your concerns you could probably accept the answer as well.